# Filter for Quarter and year filter in highstock chart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am using Highstock chart and I want a filter for Quarter and Year. I have one value for the entire year. I was updating the data using setData.Filters are not working properly, Can anyone have the idea?

rangeSelector: {
        inputEnabled: false,
         selected: 1,
         buttons: [{
          type: 'month',
          text: 'M',
          events: {
            click: function (e) {
              Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData("");
              Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].setData("");
              mscServices.getRecoveryDetailGraph()
                       .then(data => {
                        Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData(data.response.expenses);
                        Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].setData(data.response.recovery);
                       })
                       Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({
                        labels: {
                         format: '{value: %b %y}' // change format on click
                        }
                      });

```
          setTimeout(function () {
            let d, d2;
            d = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()-1).getTime();
            d2 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 2 ).getTime();
            Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(d, d2);
          }, 1);
        }
    }
    }, {
      type: 'month',
      count: 3,
      text: 'Q',
      events: {
        click: function (e) {
          Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData("");
          Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].setData("");
            Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData([
            [1546300800000, 185000],
            [1554076800000, 155000],
            [1561939200000, 200000],
            [1569888000000, 185000]

           ]);
           Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].setData([
            [1546300800000, 337889.84],
            [1554076800000, 38399],
            [1561939200000, 38555],
            [1569888000000, 5000]

            ]);
            Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({
            labels: {
            formatter: function () {
              var quarter;
              if(new Date(this.value).getMonth()== 0){
                quarter=1;
              }else if(new Date(this.value).getMonth()== 3){
                quarter=2;
              }else if(new Date(this.value).getMonth()== 6){
                quarter=3;
              }else if(new Date(this.value).getMonth()== 9){
                quarter=4;
              }
              console.log("valueee",new Date(this.value).getMonth());
              return 'Q'+quarter;
            }
          }
        });
        }
      }
    },
    {
      text: '1 Year',
      type: 'test',
      click: function() {
        Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData("");
        Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].setData("");
              Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].setData([[1546300800000,17282]]);
              Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].setData([[1546300800000,37833]]);
              Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({
                  labels: {
                    format: '{value: %Y}' // change format on click
                  }
                });
       }
    }],
  },
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? Try to be more precise also, thanks.